# How to mock basic_get function?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pika

I would like to mock pika basic_get function which is not directly imported in any of my modules. Result output points to MagicMock object, but when I call basic_get directly in the testing function, mocking works. What steps could I take to solve this issue?

cli.py

```
@click.command
def main():
    connection, channel = get_con()
    message = channel.basic_get('some_queue', no_ack=True)
    print(message)
```

con.py

```
def get_con.py
    parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqp://')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    return connection, channel
```

test.py

```
@patch('pika.channel.Channel.basic_get')
def test_something(basic_get_mock):
    with patch('con.get_con', return_value=(MagicMock(), MagicMock())) as get_con_mock:
        basic_get_mock.return_value = 45
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(main)
        print(result.output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already mocking `get_con`, so there's no need to mock the original class; just configure the mock you are already creating.

```
def test_something():
    mock_conn = MagicMock()
    mock_channel = MagicMock()
    with patch('con.get_con', return_value=(mock_conn, mock_channel)):
        mock_channel.basic_get.return_value = 45
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(main)
        print(result.output)
```